# Stop PHP from echoing specific tags (but still echo others)

Tags: php, html

I've been wondering if it's possible to "blacklist" specific HTML tags from printing (but *still* allow other tags to echo, so not strip_tags).

So basically, if I wanted to block the `h1` tag, instead of:

## Hello World

My code would echo out:

```
<h1>Hello World</h1>
```

Any of you guys know if it's possible, and if it is, what should I do to achieve this?

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: @JayBlanchard I've asked questions like this on SO before. Did the policy change?

Comment: Any question asking "is it possible" and "how do I do this if it is possible" are way too broad.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Apologies, I wasn't aware...

Comment: I think know how to do what I think you're asking, but I am not sure what you're asking. Are you asking PHP to make certain HTML unrenderable?

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yeah. I Googled a bit, and couldn't find a good answer

Comment: @JayBlanchard Thanks. I'll refrain from writing questions like this in the future

Comment: I posted the basic, a function will take a lot more time because of complex regex. I'll edit and add that once done and tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve making tags unrenderable is to replace the tags using character entities for the braces. For example:

```
$string = "<h1>foobar</h1>";
$unrender = str_replace(array('<', '>'), array('&lt;', '&gt;') ,$string);
echo $unrender;
```

Which returns:

```
&lt;h1&gt;foobar&lt;/h1&gt;
```

Which gets rendered like this:

> <h1>foobar</h1>

Next step is making this a basic function which would handle all tags in a given string:

```
function unrender($element) {
    $lbracket = '/<(.*?)/';
    $rbracket = '/>/';
    $l = preg_replace($lbracket, '&lt;', $element);
    $r = preg_replace($rbracket, '&gt;', $l);

    return $r;        
}

$string = "<h1>foobar</h1><br />";
echo unrender($string);
```

You get:

```
&lt;h1&gt;foobar&lt;/h1&gt;&lt;br /&gt;
```

Which renders like this:

> <h1>foobar</h1><br />

The next improvement would be allowing a list of blacklisted tags. At this point I feel obligated to say a  [a PHP DOM parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) makes performing something like this much easier. Here is the proposed process:

1. for each tag in an array like `$blacktag = array('h1', 'h2', 'p');` locate the tag to be unrendered (regex involved unless using a DOM parser)
2. unrender the tag in the list by replacing the angle brackets properly.

On the surface this sounds easy, but consider matching tags don't match. The beginning is different than the end (by virtue of the `/`). Then, take into account you may have something like this, where a thing that looks like a tag, isn't <h2>H20 is water, not a tag</h2>

It becomes quite the complex challenge. Even a "simple" function in which you pass the text and the single tag you want to unrender becomes a challenge.